# Error on gcloud with tensorflow.python.keras.applications for machine learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sdk, gcloud

Im working with gcloud and I got this error:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_main.py", line 25, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 30, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter as exporter_lib
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 37, in <module>
    from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/deepmac_meta_arch.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.models.keras_models import resnet_v1
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/models/keras_models/resnet_v1.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.applications import resnet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications'
```

My `requeriments.txt` file is:

```
six
google-api-python-client>=1.6.7
kaggle>=1.3.9
Keras-Applications
numpy>=1.15.4
oauth2client
pandas>=0.22.0
psutil>=5.4.3
py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0
scipy>=0.19.1
tensorflow-hub>=0.6.0
tensorflow-model-optimization
tensorflow-model-optimization>=0.4.1
tensorflow-addons
dataclasses;python_version<"3.7"
gin-config
tf_slim>=1.1.0
Cython
matplotlib
# Loader becomes a required positional argument in 6.0 in yaml.load
pyyaml>=5.1,<6.0
# CV related dependencies
opencv-python-headless
Pillow
pycocotools
# NLP related dependencies
seqeval
sentencepiece
sacrebleu
```

From my terminal I used this code to run the machine learning:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training segmentation_maskrcnn_img_53 ^
    --runtime-version 2.5 ^
    --python-version 3.7 ^
    --job-dir=gs://meat-segmentation-img/training_process ^
    --package-path ./object_detection ^
    --module-name object_detection.model_main ^
    --region us-central1 ^
    --scale-tier CUSTOM ^
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-16 ^
    --master-accelerator count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-t4 ^
    -- ^
    --model_dir=gs://meat-segmentation-img/training_process ^
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://meat-segmentation-img/mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_gpu-8.config
```

I used runtime version 2.7 but I got this error:

ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_group_columns.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

How I fix this?

I'm using this from Windows by conda environment.

Comment: Edit your question. Remove the screenshot and post the error message as text.

Comment: @JohnHanley some suggestion??

Comment: Edit your question and include the code that generated the error and **requirements.txt**. Is there a reason you are using runtime-version 2.5 instead of 2.7?

Comment: I used 2.7 but I got other error.

Comment: believe this to be a documented bug...

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10480

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify the code for importing keras applications as

`from tensorflow.keras import applications`

in place of

`from tensorflow.python.keras import applications`.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications) link for more details.